# Calculate time in certain state for time series data

Tags: python, pandas

I have an irregularly indexed time series of data with seconds resolution like:

```
import pandas as pd
idx = ['2012-01-01 12:43:35', '2012-03-12 15:46:43', 
       '2012-09-26 18:35:11', '2012-11-11 2:34:59']
status = [1, 0, 1, 0]
df = pd.DataFrame(status, index=idx, columns = ['status'])
df = df.reindex(pd.to_datetime(df.index))

In [62]: df
Out[62]: 
                     status
2012-01-01 12:43:35       1
2012-03-12 15:46:43       0
2012-09-26 18:35:11       1
2012-11-11 02:34:59       0
```

and I am interested in the fraction of the year when the status is 1. The way I currently do it is that I reindex `df` with every second in the year and use forward filling like:

```
full_idx = pd.date_range(start = '1/1/2012', end = '12/31/2012', freq='s')
df1 = df.reindex(full_idx, method='ffill')
```

which returns a `DataFrame` that contains every second for the year which I can then calculate the mean for, to see the percentage of time in the `1` status like:

```
In [66]: df1
Out[66]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 31536001 entries, 2012-01-01 00:00:00 to 2012-12-31 00:00:00
Freq: S
Data columns:
status    31490186  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1)


In [67]: df1.status.mean()
Out[67]: 0.31953371123308066
```

The problem is that I have to do this for a lot of data, and reindexing it for every second in the year is most expensive operation by far.

What are better ways to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a pandas method to compute time differences between entries of an irregular time series, though there is a convenience method to convert a time series index to an array of `datetime.datetime` objects, which can be converted to `datetime.timedelta` objects through subtraction.

```
In [6]: start_end = pd.DataFrame({'status': [0, 0]},
                                 index=[pd.datetools.parse('1/1/2012'),
                                        pd.datetools.parse('12/31/2012')])

In [7]: df = df.append(start_end).sort()

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
                     status
2012-01-01 00:00:00       0
2012-01-01 12:43:35       1
2012-03-12 15:46:43       0
2012-09-26 18:35:11       1
2012-11-11 02:34:59       0
2012-12-31 00:00:00       0

In [9]: pydatetime = pd.Series(df.index.to_pydatetime(), index=df.index)

In [11]: df['duration'] = pydatetime.diff().shift(-1).\
              map(datetime.timedelta.total_seconds, na_action='ignore')

In [16]: df
Out[16]: 
                     status  duration
2012-01-01 00:00:00       0     45815
2012-01-01 12:43:35       1   6145388
2012-03-12 15:46:43       0  17117308
2012-09-26 18:35:11       1   3916788
2012-11-11 02:34:59       0   4310701
2012-12-31 00:00:00       0       NaN

In [17]: (df.status * df.duration).sum() / df.duration.sum()
Out[17]: 0.31906950786402843
```

Note:

- Our answers seem to differ because I set `status` before the first timestamp to zero, while those entries are NA in your `df1` as there's no start value to forward fill and NA values are excluded by pandas mean().
- [`timedelta.total_seconds()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) is new in Python 2.7.
- Timing comparison of this method versus reindexing:

  ```
  In [8]: timeit delta_method(df)
  1000 loops, best of 3: 1.3 ms per loop

  In [9]: timeit redindexing(df)
  1 loops, best of 3: 2.78 s per loop
  ```

Comment: this is calculating is missing a day: it's using the fraction of the time between the start of 1/1/2012 and the *start* of 12/31/2012,

Answer (score 2):

Another potential approach is to use [traces](http://traces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```py
import traces
from dateutil.parser import parse as date_parse

idx = ['2012-01-01 12:43:35', '2012-03-12 15:46:43', 
       '2012-09-26 18:35:11', '2012-11-11 2:34:59']
status = [1, 0, 1, 0]

# create a TimeSeries from date strings and status
ts = traces.TimeSeries(default=0)
for date_string, status_value in zip(idx, status):
    ts[date_parse(date_string)] = status_value

# compute distribution  
ts.distribution(
    start=date_parse('2012-01-01'),
    end=date_parse('2013-01-01'),
)
# {0: 0.6818022667476219, 1: 0.31819773325237805}
```

The value is calculated between the start of January 1, 2012 and *end* of December 31, 2012 (equivalently the start of January 1, 2013) without resampling, and assuming the status is `0` at the start of the year (the `default=0` parameter)

Timing results:

```py
In [2]: timeit ts.distribution(
    start=date_parse('2012-01-01'),
    end=date_parse('2013-01-01')
)
619 µs ± 7.25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```